# Use Client side table to pass multiple values to Database c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I need to pass values from a client side table or gridview like controls to the database. I am currently using C# webforms and as I experience it is not possible to this with webforms because I am bound to use asp controls. I need to use a lighter control like html or razor that does not wait for server to respond before it adds a rows due to the reason that I am developing an application that requires rapid barcode scanning (split seconds per add).

What I already tried:

I used a non database gridview to get values then I pass all row values to database at a single event  - RESULT : Slow on adding rows, since it sends request before you can add new row even if there is no database involve.

I already tried to use javascript to have a gridviewlike table which consists of multiple textboxes then pass it to the database after populating the rows - RESULT: This almost solved my problem because when I use javascript to add 'rows' it is pure client side which is really fast. But my problem is I can not get all textbox's values to pass it all at once. The least I can do with this is to loop my query per textboxes which is very slow.

Please advice what should I do. If this is possible with MVC may I know. I already spent so much days with this. I even looked for examples of c# MVC that uses this method but I could'nt see any. I am a database guy and I am new to programming please bear with me. I would really appreciate your help.

This is the second method I tried. This is fast since I used JS to add rows to the dummy gridview but I can not get all row values to insert it to the database at once. I am forced to loop my query on each rows.

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string bundle = Session["bundleid"].ToString();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_forbindgrid", sqlConnection1);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MANIFESTID", bundle);

        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }

    }

    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        //If no records then add a dummy row.
        dt.Rows.Add();
    }

    gvCustomers.DataSource = dt;
    gvCustomers.DataBind();
}

protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] names = Request.Form["name"].Split(',');
    string[] countries = Request.Form["country"].Split(',');
    string userfid = User.Identity.Name;
    string manifestid = Session["bundleid"].ToString();
    string nextoffice = Session["officecode"].ToString();

    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_forbatchinsert"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userfid", userfid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MANIFESTID", manifestid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NEXTOFFICE", nextoffice);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRACKINGNO", countries[i]);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }            
    }

Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);     
}
```

This is the Javascript I used to populate the dummy GridView

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddRow() {
    var gridView = document.getElementById("<%=gvCustomers.ClientID %>");
    var tbody = gridView.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var row = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1];

    if (row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '') == "") {
        tbody.removeChild(row);
    }

    row = row.cloneNode(true);
    var txtName = document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClientID %>");
    SetValue(row, 0, "name", txtName);
    var txtCountry = document.getElementById("<%=txtCountry.ClientID %>");
    SetValue(row, 1, "country", txtCountry);

    tbody.appendChild(row);
    return false;
    };

function SetValue(row, index, name, textbox) {
    row.cells[index].innerHTML = textbox.value;
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = name;
    input.value = textbox.value;
    row.cells[index].appendChild(input);
    textbox.value = "";
}
</script>
```

Then this is my GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" CssClass = "table" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COUNT" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-CssClass="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("COUNT") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TRACKING" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-CssClass="Country">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("TRACKING")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and my input controls

```
<asp:table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Name:<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="140" Text="" />
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Country:<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Width="140" Text="" />
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClientClick="return AddRow()" />
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:table>
<br />

<asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit" />
```

Comment: You can do it with Web Forms, you don't have to use MVC, though MVC is a bit easier to work with if you want to have a richer client side. But before we can tell you what you're doing wrong, you have to *show your code*.

Comment: @mason I am new here at stackoverflow so please wait til I figure out to post my code. Just a sec. thanks

Comment: You click the edit button on your question. Make sure the the left most indention of your code is 4 spaces, and that there's at least two line breaks between your text and your code. Note that we don't need all of your code. Just enough for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There it is @mason. My code.

Comment: You could modify your form so that each new row has unique name, then in your server side code you can dig those values out of the post request, add the rows to the database as appropriate, and rebind. I don't have time at the moment to create an example of that, but I really don't recommend you do that anyways. Instead what I would do is post each submitted row to the system via AJAX, and in the client side code also add the new row to the HTML table. You'll need a server side component to handle the AJAX request, probably either Web API or a generic handler (.ashx).

Comment: I see. I will try that. I will read about AJAX and Web APIs . BTW mason thanks for editing the code for me to make the question more comprehensive. Thank you.